# Changing root password in PHPMyAdmin for Wordpress Database when going live

Tags: database, mysql, phpmyadmin

Is it a good idea to create a password and make your password secure for your Wordpress database when uploading the database to a third-party web host (going live instead of hosting on localhost) instead of root and no password? :

Change

u. root
p. 'no password'

to

u. username
p. password

Does it make your database more secure and still accessible to your new third-party host?

Comment: If the database is exposed to the internet, you could be able to use something like `mysql -u root -h yoursite.com` to connect to your database and create tables, modify data, or just delete everything, anybody would be able to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes. Having a secure username and password is paramount to keeping your site secure.

Comment: But, having a secure password for the database, (and the admin to the site) right?

Comment: @Joseph yes, what's to stop somebody from just connecting to your database directly and making changes? The only time you're ok setting a user/password to something simple is if you want it to be hacked or accessed/changed by the general public